# Using a checkbox to trigger different conditions - javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox, adobe

I'm struggling with how to write code that is tied to a button on adobe. When I press it, it checks if checkbox is true or false and then saves it in FolderA or folderB.

Checkbox is unique, the export value is set to true in the properties.

```
var myFileName = this.getField("Text Field 5").value + ".pdf";

if (this.getField("checkbox") == "true") { // I cannot get this condition to trigger

myFileName = "C:/Documents/FolderA/" + myFileName
myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc(this, myFileName);

}

else  { //this condition always triggers

myFileName = "C:/Documents/FolderB/" + myFileName
myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc(this, myFileName);
}
```

When I click the button, only the else condition triggers, I havent been able to determine while the if condition doesnt trigger.

Comment: It's because maybe `this.getField("field")` is returning anything but not a string. Can you update the question to append the code of that method?

Comment: ok, so rather than comparing it to  a string ie "true", I should create a boolean data type and check if they are equal? I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Yes, that's the right thing. `getField` method should return a boolean, you need to assure that.